# How to solve Google map conflict with other jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I'm building wordpress website and I added Google map using this code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;v=3.exp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://sabastudios.com/ext/responsive-maps-plugin/includes/js/jquery.gmap.min.js?ver=3.3.3'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var mapdiv = jQuery("#responsive_map_1932889777");
    mapdiv.gMapResp({
      maptype: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 17,
      markers: [{
                    address: '1 Hermann Park Ct #634 Houston, Texas 77021', 
                    html:'<img src=\'http://motiongiraffx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/marker.png\' width=\'100px\'><br><br /> 1 Hermann Park Ct #634 <br/>Houston, Texas 77021',
                    popup: true,
                    flat: true,
                    icon: {    
                        iconsize: [100, 75],
                        iconanchor: null,
                        shadowsize: [50, 50],
                        shadowanchor: null}}],
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      draggable: true,
      scrollwheel: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: true,
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null     });
  });
    window.onresize = function() {
        jQuery('.responsive-map').each(function(i, obj) {
            var gmap = jQuery(this).data('gmap').gmap;
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, 'resize');
            jQuery(this).gMapResp('fixAfterResize');
        });
  };
    </script>
  <div id="responsive_map_1932889777" class="responsive-map" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></div>
```

but when I add any other jQuery plugin I got error for map that Cannot read property 'gmap' of undefined . I suppose that there is conflict, but I don't know how to fix it.

For example I want to add those two plugins

http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/
http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/fade-down/

What is the best way to solve those conflicts in WordPress or between plugins?

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a problem with the script loading. Can you post a url? Or check from your resources that the script is really loaded?

Comment: This is the link to my website. I added Scroll effects plugin and my map stop working. If I remove that plugin map works. I'm not sure what is the problem. Map should stay under contact form section. And also I'm getting error for this plugin too that his function is not a function.

Comment: I'm including scripts in function.php file using wordpress wp_enqueue_script() function.

Comment: Is jQuery.js being included more than once in the page? Any plugins attached to one version will be wiped out by a subsequent version being loaded

Comment: I don't see the link to your page?

Comment: Here is the link http://motiongiraffx.com/ . Sorry.

Comment: Also I noticed now that one more jQuery plugin that I have on website is destroyed on page http://motiongiraffx.com/about-us/ . Plugin name is lightslider.js . This all happens when I add Scroll effects plugin.

Comment: @charlietfl No, jQuery is included only once, I checked in console in Resource tab. Every script is included only once.